# Ponteiro não consegue ser resetado pra NULL dentro de função

Tags: c++, ponteiro, funções, árvore-binária

Olá, pessoal! Eu estava estudando arvores binárias e precisei criar uma função que removesse um nó qualquer e seus filhos. No entanto, quando eu fiz essa função com o retorno /*1*/ o nó não foi removido. Copiando o retorno de outra função da minha arvore, eu escrevi o retorno /*2*/, substituindo o /*1*/.
A minha pergunta é: de acordo com apenas esse pedaço de código, existe alguma razão pra /*1*/ não funcionar?

```
Node * remover(Node *root, int valor){
if(root == NULL){
    cout<<"Elemento não encontrado."<<endl; 
}
else{
    if(root->data == valor){
        root = NULL; // isso não modifica o ponteiro? Por quê?
        cout<<"Elemento removido!"<<endl;
        return root;
    }
    if(root->data > valor){
        /* 1 */ //remover(root->left,valor); não funciona
        /* 2 */root->left = remover(root->left,valor); // funciona
        return root;
    }
    if(root->data < valor){
        /* 1 */ //remover(root->right,valor);  não funciona
        /* 2 */root->right = remover(root->right,valor); // funciona        
        return root;        
    }
}
}
```

Consequentemente, por que essa parte não funciona ?:

```
    if(root->data == valor){
        root = NULL; // isso não modifica o ponteiro? Por quê?
        cout<<"Elemento removido!"<<endl;
        return root;
    }
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Quando você faz `root = NULL`, você está modificando o valor da variável local `root`. Se você deseja que uma função receba um ponteiro como parâmetro e o modifique, você precisa de um ponteiro para ponteiro.

A assinatura da sua função ficaria assim:

```
Node * remover(Node **root, int valor);
```

e a linha que atualmente não funciona ficaria assim:

```
*root = NULL;
```

A propósito, a não ser que você tenha bons motivos para não fazê-lo, prefira `nullptr` para representar ausência de valor. Essa é a constante nula que oferece segurança de tipagem em C++ (diferente de `NULL`, que é simplesmente um apelido para a constante `0`). Para isso, certifique-se de estar compilando no modo C++11.

Comment: Alternativamente você também pode usar uma referência para o ponteiro (`Node *&root`).

Comment: @Pablo, já tinha passado pela minha cabeça que isso seria algum problema relacionado ao fato de eu n ter usado um ponteiro para ponteiro, já que eu vi outras arvores na internet que usavam esse tipo de parâmetro. Mas como eu não entendo muito de ponteiros de ponteiros eu não tinha certeza se era isso mesmo. Vou estudar um pouco mais pra aprender a lidar com isso e muito obrigado pela resposta e pela dica sobre o `nullptr`, me ajudaram bastante.